# Find The nearest date range from Another date table and join the data in one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you find The nearest date range from Another date table  and join  the data in one table when they are share same ID?

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_A
    ([ID] int, [StartDate] datetime,[EndDate] datetime )
;
INSERT INTO TAB_A
    ([ID], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES
    (101, '2014-03-01 00:00:00', '2014-03-02 00:00:00'),
    (102, '2014-03-03 00:00:00', '2014-03-10 00:00:00'),
    (103, '2014-03-06 00:00:00', '2014-03-11 00:00:00'),
    (104, '2014-03-01 00:00:00', '2014-03-13 00:00:00'),
    (105, '2014-03-01 00:00:00', '2014-03-20 00:00:00')
;
CREATE TABLE TAB_B
    ([ID] int, [StartDate] datetime,[EndDate] datetime )
;   
INSERT INTO TAB_B
    ([ID], [StartDate], [EndDate])
VALUES
    (101, '2014-02-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-02 00:00:00'),
    (101, '2014-03-01 00:00:00', '2014-03-05 00:00:00'),
    (102, '2014-03-03 00:00:00', '2014-03-10 00:00:00'),
    (102, '2014-04-03 00:00:00', '2014-04-30 00:00:00'),
    (102, '2014-01-03 00:00:00', '2014-02-10 00:00:00'),
    (103, '2014-03-07 00:00:00', '2014-03-10 00:00:00'),
    (103, '2014-03-11 00:00:00', '2014-03-20 00:00:00'),
    (103, '2014-03-30 00:00:00', '2014-03-31 00:00:00'),
    (104, '2014-02-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-14 00:00:00'),
    (105, '2014-03-02 00:00:00', '2014-03-19 00:00:00'),
    (105, '2014-03-01 00:00:00', '2014-03-20 00:00:00'),
```

Result

```
(T1[ID],      T1[StartDate],            T1[EndDate],      T2[ID],  T2[StartDate],        T2[EndDate])
(   101, '2014-03-01 00:00:00', '2014-03-02 00:00:00' , 101, '2014-02-29 00:00:00', '2014-03-02 00:00:00')
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, please give what is expected outcome of your question and explain what do you mean by nearest date range and join it with another table.

Comment: So far i was think join two table when the are same ID and date and calculate the absolute value different between each start point and end point but then how i only return the data that has the lowest absolute value.

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS:** you should use`GROUP BY` and `MIN MAX` to achieve the desired output as below. You can either do it for single record by adding `ID` in `WHERE` clause or for all by removing `WHERE` clause

```
 SELECT t1.id AS [T1ID], 
    MIN(t1.StartDate) AS [T1StartDate], 
    MIN(t1.EndDate) AS [T1EndDate], 
    MAX(t2.id) [T2ID], 
    MIN(t2.StartDate) AS [T2StartDate], 
    MIN(t2.EndDate) AS [T2EndDate]
 FROM TAB_A t1
 INNER JOIN TAB_B t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
 WHERE t1.id = 101
 GROUP BY t1.id --Not needed if we select `ID` by using `MIN or MAX`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If in Table TAB_A  ID is not repeated and you are passing same ID in Where condition than you can use below query also

SELECT t1.id             AS [T1ID], 
       t1.startdate      AS [T1StartDate], 
       t1.enddate        AS [T1EndDate], 
       t2.id             [T2ID], 
       Min(t2.startdate) AS [T2StartDate], 
       Min(t2.enddate)   AS [T2EndDate] 
FROM   tab_a t1 
       INNER JOIN tab_b t2 
               ON t1.id = t2.id 
                  AND t1.id = 101 
GROUP  BY t1.id, 
          t1.startdate, 
          t1.enddate, 
          t2.id
```